# directive using other directive - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directive, I want to count how much sons in father tag and display the counter in index.html as shown after JS files, the problem is that I didn't get the number correctly

```
   module.directive('directiveFather', function () {

    return {

    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    controller: function ($scope) {

        $scope.AllCounter = 0;

        this.addCounter = function () {

            $scope.AllCounter = $scope.AllCounter + 1;

        }

    }


}
```

})

```
  module.directive('directiveSon', function () {

return {

    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    require: '^directiveFather',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, fatherCtrl){
      fatherCtrl.addCounter();
     }
    }


}
```

})

```
<directive father>

 <directive son>

 </directive son>
 {{AllCounter}}

 </directive father>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an isolate scope, then the elements inside `directiveFather` will be bound to the parent scope (thus `AllCounter` won't be directly available in the view - although it will hold the correct value).

---

You can either change `scope: {}` to `scope: true/false` in `directiveFather` (see [demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/4p77kne7/)) or
"manually" compile, link and append the HTML to the `directiveFather` element (see [demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/4p77kne7/1/)).
(There is, also, [Wildhoney's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752991/directive-using-other-directive-angularjs/25753441#comment-40287495) of using transclusion and `template`.)

<sub>Basically, you don't need any of that for the approach to work - they are only necessary to demonstrate that everything works (by displaying the counter in the view), but even without appending the counter, the `addChild()` function gets called as expected.</sub>

---

That said, after fixing the element names (`<directive-father>` and `<directive-son>`), it works as expected.

---

See, also, these short demos: **[demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/4p77kne7/)**, **[demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/4p77kne7/1/)**.

Comment: Otherwise implement it using the `factory`/`service` approach.

Comment: The problem with the factory/service approach is that the implementation for supporting multiple `directiveFather` instances will be considerably more complex.

Comment: Don't you want something like the following: [http://jsfiddle.net/abzf0mem/](http://jsfiddle.net/abzf0mem/)?